# http request timeout on error android app

Tags: android, http, kotlin, okhttp

Hi i have a server app that is run on my computer and in order to use it on my android application i used serveo to get a global domain for my localhost like this :

```
ssh -R myexpressjsproject:80:localhost:3000 serveo.net
```

and on my android application i do post like this:

```
fun getServerResponse(json : String){
    val neabyURL = url + "nearby"
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setWriteTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    val JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json;charset=utf-8")
    val Body = RequestBody.create(JSON , json)
    val newReq = Request.Builder()
        .url(neabyURL)
        .post(Body)
        .build()
    try{

        val response : Response = client.newCall(newReq).execute()
        val responseStr : String = response.body().string()
        val Jobject = JSONObject(responseStr)
        lastCheckId = Jobject.getString("ca")


    }catch (e : Exception){
        Log.i("sending" , "problem happened")

        e.printStackTrace()
        return
    }
}
```

the problem is that my API's randomly got this error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

and every time is one of my API's that get this error although i get my requests response immediately on postman and there is no error on my server side application.
do you think this is because of the serveo thing and it will be solved if i run it on a real server or it is because of my android code?

Comment: Do you get the same timeout problems if you use `curl` to make the same request from the command line?

Comment: @Enselic no there is no problem with curl